# What happened to this added directory in environment variables path?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, environment-variables

Added the following directory to the path by using this method:

set path=%path%;D:\Programm\jflex-1.8.2\jflex-1.8.2\bin
set path=%path%;D:\Programm\jflex-1.8.2\jflex-1.8.2\bin\jflex

but, I can't find it in GUI (user/system):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVn56.jpg

But by using echo(%path:;=&echo.% got this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ9j7.jpg

Now I've got a few problems:

1. How do I remove jflex from the path using cmd (preferably)?
2. Where is it? Cause I can't see it in system environment values but somehow it's still there (with cmd)?
3. Update1: What just happened?

BTW the jflex command does work, so it is in path and working perfectly fine.

Update0: Not in Registry (I think I looked at the right place, if not tell me):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhy0X.jpg

Update1: Ok, now this is weird, now it's gone...what happened exactly?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ako0J.jpg

Comment: Where is it? Cause I can't see in in system environment values but somehow it's still there    ... I do not and probably will never why people spread Windows all over creation.   Look in the Registry for the value you want and see where it might be.

Comment: @John hmm...it was not in there...updated post.

Comment: If it is not in Environment variables (System Properties) and does not show up in a Registry search, then it could be anywhere.   Consider rebuilding your computer and keeping Windows (all of it) on drive C:

Comment: @John I'm not sure if that's the right solution.

Comment: I don’t see any other way to correct the problem. It will be much faster to back up and rebuild than finding a needle in a haystack

Comment: @John ...do you know any way to modify the values in path from command line? I've read some other posts related to this similar problem and there were solutions for those but idk how to with this one, that's why I asked. I'm not so good with command line so...hmm there has to be a way tho

Comment: The command line has to know where the path is, and you cannot edit within the command. You would have to see if you can paste the command with the path into Notepad

Comment: There are so many things wrong here.  First of all, your `set path` statements from cmd.exe did NOTHING outside of that specific instance of cmd.exe.  They weren't permanent.  1)  Open a fresh cmd.exe  2) type `where jflex` 3) type `set path` and you will see that it isn't on the end. 4) The registry has two places for environment, not one.  [One is system wide and one is current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573817/where-are-environment-variables-stored-in-the-windows-registry).  If the thing you are looking for isn't in there, then it isn't a thing.

Comment: There are so many things wrong here ....  and ... Windows was spread all over the place.  ....  This is why I suggest you (post author) rebuild your machine properly with Windows all on drive C:

Comment: @señor-cmasmas Thanks for the explanation I'll look it up.
also John right now windows somehow removed it from the path like I explained it in the updated post so there is absolutely no reason to rebuild the system, I fixed the jflex path and everything is working fine.